# Credit card fee to the final order in CP

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I need to add the credit card fee to the order in the CP. I get a response from the gateway with a custom txnfee variable and would like to view it in the CP. Just like an custom adjuster. Does anyone have any experience with that?

Example:

Order = $100
Tax = $5
Credit card fee = $1
Total = $106

Comment: Isn't this identical to your other question? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17371/save-and-show-card-fee-for-commerce-plugin

Comment: Yes I guess it is. But this is more general in terms of an overall solution for saving all the gateway response data for easy readability in the CP.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the response to an incognito field (or fields) on your order (probably both the entire response and also just the fee separate out).

https://github.com/mmikkel/IncognitoField-Craft

The `readonly` incognito field is particularly good for this sort of thing - I use a bunch of these fields in a debug tab on my order layout to save useful things.

Just create the fields, add the fields to your order, and you update the values with the usual `<input name="fields[fieldName]">` syntax with any cart operation, or use `setContentFromPost` if you're in a plugin:

```
    $order->setContentFromPost(array(
        'fieldName' => $creditCardFee,
    ));
    craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order);
```